# How can a transistor lose its gain?

Tags: transistors, bjt, heat, gain

I do a lot of old radio repairs and I have always been told that the way to test a BJT transistor is to check its junctions which should work as diodes. But many times, I noticed that despite the working junctions, the transistor have a very weak or even no gain at all.

This very often happens with power transistors that have suffered from excessive heat. And it sometimes also happens with RF transistors located at the IF, mixer or local oscillator stages in radios. These transistors should never heat since they drive very small currents.

So, what are the exact reasons that make a transistor lose its gain? And what happens exactly at the junctions level?

Comment: One of the reaons could be diffusion. As transistors get heated, their dopants diffuse. This is a very (very very) gradual proces, but given the production methods of very old radio transitors, and the time they have had for this process to take place, it could be that this is (in part) to blame. I have no numbers and am far from certain, hence I'm not putting it in a propper answer.

Comment: In FETs, there is also the matter of hot-electron injection shifting Vt, but I don't think old transistors were anywhere small enough for this to become a problem.
And finaly, there is the matter of electromigration that might have infuluenced the resistances. Again, all of this is wild speculation.

Comment: @racboni .Are you talking about PNP Ge transistors ?

Comment: "These transistors should never heat since they drive very small currents" - but they were often _rated_ for very small currents, so it might not take much to blow them.

Comment: @Autistic I am talking about all BJT transistors. I noticed this problem in PNP, NPN, Ge and silicon transistors. But it seems that Ge transistors are more subject to gain loss.

Comment: @BruceAbbott yes you are right. But here the transistors are not really blown. The junctions are still working as diodes. Only the hfe gain is affected.

Comment: High HFE requires almost all carriers injected by "emitter" to *miss* the base charges and continue on to the "collector". If the base recombination is 0.01, beta is ~100. If recombination increases, due to age and diffusion of dopants, the beta declines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There could be different causes depending on the type and construction of  transistor, and any environmental stresses it has been exposed to. These may include diffusion of atoms in the semiconductor, electromigration of the metalization, contamination by water or oxygen, excessive voltage or current and mechanical or thermal stress.

I could not find any information relating to this failure mode in germanium transistors, but I did find an [article](http://downloads.hindawi.com/journals/apec/2001/053209.pdf) on the degradation of silicon transistors, which says this:-

> The current gain of bipolar transistors strongly decreases when
>   the oxide over the emitter-base junction is damaged. This can
>   occur in normal operation conditions since, when the emitter-base
>   junction is reverse-biased, hot carriers are created...
>
> the base-collector junction is not degraded by 
>   the stress.

The accompanying graphs show dramatic gain reduction,

[image]

but relatively normal Base-Emitter diode action.

[image]

It may be that germanium transistors are now getting old enough to show signs of degradation during normal use, however the failures of this type that I have come across were all silicon transistors that were stressed by over-voltage.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. I really appreciate. I have just read the entire document. Very interesting.

Comment: BTW I tested my collection of old germanium transistors (some new, others pulled from junked radios). Most were OK, but a few had low gain and/or high leakage, and one brand new AC128 had extremely high leakage _and_ ridiculously high gain! Unfortunately I don't know if they were always like this or whether their characteristics have drifted over time.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this can also happen (as I discovered) if a transistor that has been reverse biased ie for use as a "Negistor" it will never work well again.
Even if its only been left for a few hours, there will be a reduction in gain.
Seems to be an effective way to adjust gain though and works really well if the transistor is already damaged or poor quality as was quite common with Sinclair era ones.

Answer (score 1):

Secondary breakdown is a thermal runaway process where additional heat causes additional conductivity due to additional charge carrier mobility.  This focuses the heat in a narrowing channel that deteriorates or even melts or burns.  If this process endures or repeats often enough without losing the bonding wires, it ends up destroying particularly those areas of the transistor that are responsible for current gain, so you'll end up with independent diodes of dubious quality.

Data sheets for newer variants of 2N3055 (a classic power transistor originally from RCA) tend to have elaborate 2nd breakdown diagrams giving timing of the problem for various voltages and currents.  The reason is that when newer variants switched to an epitaxial process, the vastly increased chip homogeneity accommodated the thermal runaway process converging to a small conductivity channel, and specific measures had to be taken to recover some of the lost robustness.

Since secondary breakdown specifically affects those areas carrying the current resulting from gain, it is a likely contributor to transistors ending up without useful gain due to persistent overloading.